# Serve webjar as root resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, webjars

I have a Spring Boot server which includes a webjar with my client code. I would like to serve this webjar at the root of my service and not in the /webjar/name/version location.

I was able to remap using this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/my-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/");
    }
}
```

Still two problems here:
- I encode the version in the path, which I would like to avoid
- The resources in the webjar are still also available on the /webjar/name/version path

Any suggestions?

Comment: My current workaround is to build my webjar with content directly under `/META-INF/resources/`. This way, it's not a real webjar anymore, but it works for now. No need for resource handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- repackaging your content directly under `/META-INF/resources`
- voting for this Spring issue: [SPR-12323](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12323)

Comment: I'm using your first solution as my current workaround (see my comment). The spring issue doesn't really address the problem either since this only strips away the version number, not the artifact-id nor /webjars path.

Comment: Agreed. But it seems to be the norm for webjars.org artifacts. Unless you weren't referring to webjars.org but simple "JARs containing resources"?